# Why does this makefile target specific variable not expand as expected?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following simplified makefile and I'm trying to set different paths based on different targets.  Unfortunately, I'm not getting the results that I expect.  This is with make version 3.81.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
all:  Debug32

# Object directory set by target
Debug32:  OBJDIR = objdir32
#OBJDIR = wrongdirectory

# ObjDir is empty here. :(
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,DirUtil.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
            echo Compile: $@

Debug32: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
            echo mkdir $(OBJDIR) - $@
```

The results are as follows with no setting of OBJDIR:

```
echo Compile: /DirUtil.o
```

If I uncomment the "OBJDIR = wrongdirectory" line, I'll get the following results, which are confusing since I see both values of the variable where I think I should only see one:

```
echo mkdir objdir32 - wrongdirectory -
echo Compile: wrongdirectory/DirUtil.o
```

I'm assuming that the variables are not being expanded when I think they should, but I can't figure out how to alter this behavior.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the GNU info manual

> Variables and functions in all parts of a makefile are expanded when
>   read, except for in recipes, the right-hand sides of variable
>   definitions using '=', and the bodies of variable definitions using
>   the 'define' directive.

The target-specific variable only applies within recipes. Within

```
$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)
```

and

```
$(OBJDIR):
```

it is getting the global variable.

So working through what happens when you run `make Debug32`, it sees the contents of `OBJS` as a prerequisite, which leads to the first rule above. `$(OBJDIR)` has already been substituted with the global value, and this matches the target-name in the second rule which has also been substituted the same way.

However, when we get to the recipe:

```
    echo mkdir $(OBJDIR) - $@
```

`$(OBJDIR)` has not been substituted yet, so it gets the target-specific variable value.

**A working version**

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
all:  Debug32

# Object directory set by target
Debug32:  OBJDIR = objdir32
OBJDIR = wrongdirectory

Debug32: OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,obj.o)
OBJS = wrongobjs

Debug32: $$(OBJS)
    echo OBJS are $(OBJS)
    echo OBJDIR is $(OBJDIR)

%/obj.o: | %
    touch $@

OBJDIRS = objdir32 wrongdirectory anotherdirectory
$(OBJDIRS):
#   mkdir $(OBJDIR)
    mkdir $@
```

The main change is using `$$` in this line:

```
Debug32: $$(OBJS)
```

With only a single `$`, I get the error message

```
make: *** No rule to make target `wrongobjs', needed by `Debug32'.  Stop.
```

However, with the `$$`, I get

```
echo OBJS are objdir32/obj.o
OBJS are objdir32/obj.o
echo OBJDIR is objdir32
OBJDIR is objdir32
```

The use of secondary expansion has allowed accessing the target-specific variable in the prerequisites.

The other change is that I made `OBJS` a target-specific variable (because it is). In order to have a rule to build `OBJS` whatever its value, I had to use a pattern rule:

```
%/obj.o: | %
```

To avoid having a separate line for each object file, you could do the following instead:

```
OBJ_BASENAMES=obj.o obj2.o obj3.o

$(addprefix %/,$(OBJ_BASENAMES)): | %
    touch $@ # Replace with the proper recipe
```

The line containing the `addprefix` macro expands to

```
%/obj.o %/obj2.o %/obj3.o: | %
```

Then running `make anotherdirectory/obj2.o` creates a directory called "anotherdirectory" first, and creates a file called "obj2.o" within it.

Note all possible directories have to be listed in `OBJDIRS`. There's no way to collect all the rule-specific values of OBJDIR, so listing them is the best choice. The alternative is a `% :` rule to build any directory, which be capable of matching and building any target, which could be risky. (If you abandon the use of target-specific variables, there is another way of getting a list of directories that could be built: use variables with predictable names like `Debug32_OBJDIR` instead, and generate a list of their values using make functions.)

Alternatively, a generic rule that doesn't require listing the object files:

```
SOURCE=$(basename $(notdir $@)).cpp
DIR=$(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $@))

%.o: $$(SOURCE) | $$(DIR)
    touch $@ # Replace with proper recipe
```

There is no feature to read a rule in the context of every target, substituting in target-specific variables and acquiring a new rule for each target. Generic rules cannot be written in this way using target-specific variables.

Comment: This works, but it appears that I have to specify the Object Directory twice and each .o file twice, including a pattern rule per source file. Am I going about this all wrong?  It seems too difficult to create a simple generic makefile for two or more targets.

Comment: I've added a way to cover all the object files. I expect it is possible without listing them all (something like `%.o: $$(basename %).cpp | $$(dir $$@)`) but I haven't got it to work yet.

Comment: I've added an easier to use version and notes on having to list the directories. Mark Galeck's method for building directories looks like it could be better, though.

Answer (score 4):

a good way to handle

```
%/obj.o: | %
    touch $@

OBJDIRS = objdir32 wrongdirectory anotherdirectory
$(OBJDIRS):
    mkdir $@
```

is:

```
%/.:
    mkdir -p $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
```

then later you can just write, for any target that may need a directory

```
target: prerequisites | $$(@D)/.
    normal recipe for target
```